# ACF Radio Buttons change class Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently working with the ACF plugin in my WordPress blog.

I could manage to get the radio buttons but now I want them to change my styles.css file when selecting one... e.g. when selecting 'yes' nothing should happen but when selecting 'no' the class should change from :

```
    .post-image {
    grid-area: postimage;
}
```

to :

```
    .post-image {
    grid-area: postimage;
    display: none;
}
```

how can I do that and *where* do I need to do that?

Comment: No, it should not “change your styles.css file”. Instead, you should put rules to format the element differently, based on an _additional_ class, into your stylesheet to begin with - `.post-image.no { … }` And then when you create your HTML output, you make sure to add that class to the element’s `class` attribute, based on what your ACF field contains.

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the Style.css file as mentioned by @cbroe
You could also use basic jQuery that checks the state of your radio button.
Based on that you can add a separate class that either shows or hides your element.

something like:

On your style.css add these two styles.

```
.showimage{
  display:block;
}
.post-image{
  display:none;
}
```

Your JS would look something like:

```
$(document).on("click", 'input.check', function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.post-image').addClass('showimage');
  }else{
    $('.post-image').removeClass('showimage');
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! but I'm a bit lost now... where do I need to put the second part? I have no JS file at all...